# Which word do native speakers use when speaking of pop group member?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

I often called it 'member'. For examples She is the youngest member/There are 7 members in that group. But I saw an american member from k-pop group using the term 'band-mate' when describing his members.

so i wonder
 1. What is a dirrerence between the terms 'member' and 'bandmate'?
 2. Which is a frequently used word?(or do you use other word?)

Comment: Either of those words is fine to use depending on the circumstances. If you're not in the band, use *member*; if you are, *band-mate* will work just fine (and nobody would look askance at *member*, either).

Answer (score 5):

"Band-mate" is a term that one member of the band might use in speaking of another member of the band, or that one might use to emphasize the relationship between two people who are members of the same band.

> "Joe is my bandmate" said Fred, "and has been since we both started performing."
>
> "Judy and Chris remained band-mates through the formation and breakup of three different groups.

"Member" is the more general word and is far more common. Bandmate always emphasizes the relationship between two or more participants in the band.

Other terms such as "performer", "participant", and descriptions of a specifc role such as "lead singer", "bass player" and the like can also be used when appropriate, but member is probably the most common usage.

Comment: Yup, that's it. ***Bandmate*** (something of a "nonce word") is only normally used to reflect the relationship between one person and one or more other people in the band, whereas ***band member*** reflects the relationship between that one person and the band itself. As such, ***band-mates*** is much more likely to be used by someone who actually thinks of himself as the band ***leader, front-man*** (and the others as band ***members***) - but in the interests of harmony (no pun intended! :), he wants to downplay that distinction, so they're all (equal social status) "mates".

Comment: @FumbleFingers : Yes, or to emphasize a broken relationship: "What really hurt was that she cheated on me with a bandmate."